# 1st character of string lost in tcp socket transfer - C

Tags: c, sockets, debugging, tcp

I have set up a server and a client using linux sockets in C. For some reason the first character of the buffer I am trying to send is being lost (the bracket in the example that I've given). I thought that this would be a really easy debug over the weekend but so far I've gotten nowhere. I think that the buffer is correct before sending but wrong after sending. I am inexperienced with sockets and this is my first attempt at anything of this kind, I would really appreciate any pointers. The program (probably much updated) will be used for receiving co-ordinates from GPS tracking at the company where I am interning, it's my last day tomorrow and I would really hate to leave them with something useless that doesn't work. If I haven't given enough information then please just ask! I've tried to emulate the input I expect to receive from the client in a simple c script. I believe that the issue may be the third arguments of the send() and recv() function but I really don't know. Thanks in advance, this is my code:

server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define MYPORT 3490
#define BACKLOG 10
#define ONETRANSFER 1056
#define IDLENGTH 5

void sigchld_handler(int s) {
    while(wait(NULL) > 0);
}

char* receiveFileName(int fd) {
  char *fileName = malloc((IDLENGTH + 4) * sizeof(char));
  int numBytes;
  fileName[0] = 't';
  fileName[1] = 'a';
  fileName[2] = 'g';
  if((numBytes = recv(fd, &fileName[3], IDLENGTH, 0)) == -1) {
    /* Print to a log file here? Don't know the identity of the tag yet */
    printf("Error in receiveFileName");
    exit(1);
  } 
  fileName[IDLENGTH + 3] = '\0';
  return fileName;
}

char* receiveData(int fd, char* fileName, int dataSize) {
  int dataReceived;
  FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "ab");//If this doesn't work try w, I think append is correct though
  int i; 
  for(i = 0; i < dataSize; i++) {
    char dataBuf[ONETRANSFER]; 
    int remainingData = ONETRANSFER;
      while(((dataReceived = recv(fd, &dataBuf, ONETRANSFER, 0)) >= 0) && (remainingData > 0)) {  
    if(dataReceived == 0){ 
      printf("no data received\n");
      break;
    }

    fwrite(dataBuf, sizeof(char), strlen(dataBuf), fp);
    remainingData -= dataReceived;
    //  printf("Received %d bytes. We hope to receive %d more", dataReceived, remainingData); //For debug
    printf("i = %d\n", i);
      }
      printf("exited\n");
  }
  fclose(fp);
  //close(fd);
} 



/* Sets up socket */
int setUpSocket() {
  int sockfd;
  if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("Error setting up socket()");
        exit(1);
  }
  return sockfd;
}


/* Bind the socket */
void serverBind(int sockfd, struct sockaddr_in my_addr) {
  if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&my_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1){
    perror("Error in bind()");
    exit(1);
  } else {
    printf("Server-bind() is OK...\n");
  }
}

int receiveDataSize(int fd) {
  int dataSize, numBytes;
  char buf[4];
  if(numBytes = recv(fd, buf, 4, 0) == -1) {
    /* Connection error, undecided as to how to respond atm */
  }
  buf[2] = '\0';
  dataSize = strtol(buf, NULL, 10); /* 10 makes it decimal */
  printf("The size is %d\n", dataSize);
  return dataSize;
}

/* Listen and wait for the client */
void serverListen(int sockfd) {
  if(listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == -1) {
    perror("Server-listen() error");
    exit(1);
  } else {
    printf("Server-listen() is OK...Listening...\n");
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int sockfd, newfd;        /* listen on sock, new connection on new_fd */
  struct sockaddr_in my_addr;   /* my address info */
  struct sockaddr_in their_addr; /* their adress info */
  int sin_size;
  struct sigaction sa;
  int yes = 1;          /* Need this as a pointer later */

  sockfd = setUpSocket();

  /* Set sock options */

  if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
        perror("Error in setsockopt()");
        exit(1);
    }

  /* host byte order */
  my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  /* short, network byte order */
  my_addr.sin_port = htons(MYPORT);
  /* automatically fill with my IP */
  my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

  /* zero the rest of the struct */
  memset(&(my_addr.sin_zero), '\0', 8);

  serverBind(sockfd, my_addr);
  /* Set the server to listen for tags */
  serverListen(sockfd);

  /* clean all the dead processes */
  sa.sa_handler = sigchld_handler;
  sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
  sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;

  if(sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1){
        perror("Sigaction() error");
        exit(1);
  }

  /* accept loop */
  while(1) {
    sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    if((newfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size)) == -1) {
    perror("Error in accept()");
    continue;
    } 
    /* If weird things start to happen include a case for fork unsuccessful */
    /* This is the child process */
    if(!fork()){
      /* Maybe encorporate these two into one function? */
      char* fileName = receiveFileName(newfd);
      printf("The fileName is: %s", fileName);
      int dataSize = receiveDataSize(newfd); /* return the value as a factor of 1056 e.g forg 2112 return 2*/
      printf("The dataSize is: %d", dataSize);
      receiveData(newfd, fileName, dataSize);
      close(newfd);
      exit(0);
    } else {
      /* This is the parent process, looks silly but needed to fork */
    }
    close(newfd);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

emulate.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define PORT 3490
#define SINGLETRANSFER 1056
#define IDLENGTH 5
#define ID 12345

int setUpSocket(void) {
  int sockfd;
  if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("Error setting up socket");
    exit(1);
  }
  return sockfd;
}

void sendSize(char* buf, int fd) {
  int bufLength = strlen(buf) + 1;
  int dataSize = ((bufLength - 1) / SINGLETRANSFER) + 1; /* Number of "sections" sent */
  printf("DataSize is %d", dataSize);
  char sizeString[3]; //Here I am assuming that it wont be greater than 99 * 1056
  sprintf(sizeString, "%d", dataSize);
  if(send(fd, sizeString, 3, 0) == -1) {
    perror("Error in sendLength");
    exit(1);
  }
}

void sendId(int fd, const char* id) {
  int checkByte;
  if((checkByte = send(fd, id, IDLENGTH, 0) == -1)) {
      perror("Error in sending ID");
    }
}

void sendData(char* data, int fd) {
  int dataLength = strlen(data) + 1;
  int totalBytesWritten = 0;
  int numBytes;
  printf("data[0] is: %c", data[0]);
  while(totalBytesWritten != SINGLETRANSFER) {
    //assert(totalBytesWritten < 1056);
    if(numBytes = send(fd, data, dataLength - totalBytesWritten, 0) == -1) {
      //printf("data left: %d\n", dataLength - totalBytesWritten);
      perror("Error in sending in sendData()");
      exit(1);
       } else if (numBytes == 0) {
      //printf("%d", totalBytesWritten);
       break;
    } else {
      //printf("data left: %d\n", dataLength - totalBytesWritten);
      //printf("numbytes: %d", numBytes);
      totalBytesWritten += numBytes;
    }  
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  const char* id = "44444";  
  int sockfd, numbytes;
  char* ip = "127.0.0.1";

  /* I have no idea why but the first byte is being lost at some point, I have added a "NULL" byte at the beginning*/
    char* data = "(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,01end"; /* 1056 bytes, it's a test file, doesn't need to be pretty :) */
  struct hostent *he;
  /* The address information of the connector */
  struct sockaddr_in their_addr;

  /* Get host info */
  if((he = gethostbyname(ip)) == NULL) {
    perror("getHostbyName");
    exit(1);
  }
  /* set up the socket */
  sockfd = setUpSocket();

  /* Host byte order */
  their_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  their_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
  their_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)he->h_addr);

  /* Set rest of struct to zero */
  memset(&(their_addr.sin_zero), '\0', 8);

  if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &their_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) {
    perror("Error in connect()");
    exit(1);
  }  else {
    printf("Connected ok\n");
  }
  /* Send the tag's ID */
  sendId(sockfd, id);

  printf("size of data is: %zu\n", strlen(data));
  printf("The size of (int) data is: %d\n",(int) strlen(data));
  /* Send the size of buffer (number of iterations of 1056) */
  sendSize(data, sockfd);

  /* Send the data */
  sendData(data, sockfd);

  return 0;
}
```

*The client sends 1056 bytes of data at a time until it has ran out of data to send (I have no control over this)*

Comment: First step - wireshark.  See if the 'missing' bracket is being sent or not.  That immediately cuts your problem area down by half.

Comment: Also, put a breakpoint on 'buf[2] = '\0'; and see what is in 'char buf[4];' before you mangle it by writing the nul into the second char.  Maybe you missing bracket is in there?

Comment: @MartinJames If I print just before the "send()" in emulate.c the bracket is there, when I print just after the "recv()" in server.c it isn't.

Comment: ^^ yeah, something has probably eaten it.  I'm guessing receiveDataSize(), but you should use your debugger, and wireshark ,to see what is REALLY going on.  Just looking at code is not efficient.

Comment: @MartinJames First I send the size of the data and then the data itself. The transfer of the size of the data works fine so buf[2] = '\0' isn't causing the problem.

Comment: @MartinJames Right, I'll look into Wireshark. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, you send  all three bytes of 'char sizeString[3];' even though valid data my take up only two, the third being uninitialized.

Comment: @MartinJames Is wireshark able to sniff data being sent over localhost?

Comment: This is a lot of code to go through, and stackoverflow is not a debug on demand service. You're going to have to narrow down the issue yourself, but you could start by passing in the right address size in `bind(2)` on the server and in `connect(2)` on the client: it should be `sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)` (or `sizeof(my_addr)`). Also, this is not a good idea: `memset(&(my_addr.sin_zero), '\0', 8);`. It is not portable, because there isn't necessarily a `sin_zero` field. You should `memset(&my_addr, 0, sizeof(my_addr))` *before* setting the other fields.

Comment: IIRC, yes, wireshark can do that.

Comment: You send three bytes of size, but ask to receive four: 'if(numBytes = recv(fd, buf, 4, 0) == -1)'.  I wonder what's in the fourth byte?

Comment: At the moment I'm using a 1 digit integer for simplicity, but if it were two digits wouldn't the string be three bytes? The first two being numbers and the third being the termination character.

Comment: Yes, but you are sending an extra, uninitialized char.  This may, or may not , be relevant to your problem.  Sending three bytes and receiving four is much more suspicious.

Comment: I mean, would that not just remove one byte from the start of the data?

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves Thank you and I'm sorry. I thought that including the debug tag would be for debug questions, I'm still very new.

Comment: @MartinJames In fact, since I'm using SOCK_STREAM I'm almost sure that that's the problem, thank you very much. I'll test it now, if it is correct please could you write is as an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: Debugger.  Breakpoint. Examine buffer contents.  You should not write any code much more complex than 'Hello World', certainly not client/server, without a debugger.   Debugging skills are an absolutely essential tool for a software developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When exchanging the data size, you send three bytes of size, but ask to receive four.  Assuming that the calls actually do send three bytes, and receive four, (something that is not guaranteed, and you should check the returned values), then 'receiveDataSize()' will eat up the first byte of the data that follows:(

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of bugs in the code you provided for instance this is faulty as well :

```
while(((dataReceived = recv(fd, &dataBuf, ONETRANSFER, 0)) >= 0) && (remainingData > 0)) {  
if(dataReceived == 0){ 
  printf("no data received\n");
  break;
}

fwrite(dataBuf, sizeof(char), strlen(dataBuf), fp);
remainingData -= dataReceived;
//  printf("Received %d bytes. We hope to receive %d more", dataReceived, remainingData); //For debug
printf("i = %d\n", i);
  }
```

It should be :

```
 fwrite(dataBuf, sizeof(char), dataReceived , fp);
```